# Find all the roots of this polynomial over the Complex field

Tags: linear-algebra

In one of the lectures our porofessor asked us this question:

> It is known that $i$ is a root of the polynomial: $p(x) = x^4 + 2x^3 + 3x^2 +2x + 2$ 
> Find all of the roots of $p(x)$ over the complex field.

He solved this question by declaring a $z \in \mathbb{C} \Rightarrow p(z) = 0$ ($z$ is a root of this polynomial), and by using the conjugate of $z$ he proved that $p(\bar{z}) = 0$, which after that he used long division in some sort in order to find the roots which are: $(-1 + i, -1-i)$.

I understand how he did it, my question is, how should I best procced when I'm tackling this kind of question. It seems like a really long way and I'm sure there are better and more convenient ways.

Please note that I'm not looking for a solution, as it is not HW or assigment of some sort, just want to get a better understanding.

Thanks.

Comment: General method.  If you know one root (say $i$), then divide by $x-i$ to get a polynomial of degree $3$ with all the other roots.   Since $p(x)$ has real coefficients, we know from the root $i$ that $\overline{i} = -i$ is also a root.  So then divide by $x+i$ to get a polynomial of degree $2$ with the remaining roots.  When you finally reach degree $2$, use the quadratic formula.  I would say that, in general, this is the best way to proceed.  This particular case may have a shorter solution, but learn the general method anyway.

Comment: @GEdgar Thank you very much, much clearer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A shorter method **in this case**, even if we do not know a root in advance.  It is **not a general method** for other similar problems.

Notice the pattern in the coefficients $p(x) = x^4 + 2x^3 + 3x^2 +2x + 2$.  If that final $2$ were a $1$, then we cold easily factor it.  So proceed using that:

\begin{align}
x^4 + 2x^3 + 3x^2 +2x + 2 &= 0
\\
(x^4 + 2x^3 + 3x^2 +2x + 1) + 1 &= 0
\\
(x^2+x+1)^2+1 &= 0
\\
x^2+x+1 = i\qquad &\text{or}\qquad x^2+x+1 = -i
\end{align}
apply the quadratic formula
$$
x=i\quad\text{ or }\quad x=-1-i
\qquad\text{or}\qquad
x=-i\quad\text{ or}\quad x=-1+i
$$

---

Instead of the quadratic formula, we could use the same trick again, by noting $x^2+x+\frac14$ is easy to factor.  This is called "completing the square".